Congruences regarding $4n$-dimensional lattices
A sequence of integers $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ satisfies Gauss congruence if
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)a_{n/d}\equiv 0\pmod{n}$$
for every $n\geq 1$. Such sequences are also called Dold sequences, Newton sequences, Fermat sequences among other names.
One such example is when $a_n$ is equal to the number of points distance $n$ from the origin in the cubic lattice $\mathbb{Z}^4$. By Jacobi's four-square theorem, we have
$$a_n=\sum_{d\mid n,\,4\not\mid d}8d$$
and by Möbius inversion we obtain
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)a_{n/d}=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }4\mid n,\\ 8n & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
A similar result appears to hold for other $4n$-dimensional lattices, including the $\mathrm{D}_4$ and $\mathrm{E}_8$ lattices. Can anybody give an account of this phenomenon and an idea of what makes $4n$-dimensional lattices special?

My suspicion is that the reason you have observed this is that the theta series of the ${\rm D}{4}$ and ${\rm E}{8}$ lattices are Eisenstein series. This means that for these lattices, their representation numbers are expressible as divisor sums. The Dirichlet convolution of such a sequence with $\mu$ then leads to a power of $n$. The congruence you have mentioned fails for the Leech lattice (for which the theta series is not an Eisenstein series), although the first $n$ for which it fails is $n = 17$.
